# How do I send data from Flutter frontend to Nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, typescript, flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a lazy load feature and so far I've used `ScrollController` with my ListView.builder to track if someone has scrolled to the bottom of the page and then to record the number of the page the user is now on.

I've been able to implement this successfully but now I'm having trouble trying to send the variable called `page`, which holds an int value of how many times the user scrolled to the bottom, to my backend through an async function called `_getMoreData` which is called through my init function whenever the user reaches the bottom of the screen.

I'm not sure how to do that and unsure of the proper format to do so, here's my code in the frontend:

```
void _getMoreData() async {
  if (!isLoading) {
    // turn loading on
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    page = page + 1;

    // TRYING TO SEND IN "page" ALONG WITH THIS
    final response = await SquarePostService.getAllPosts();
    print(response?[0]);
    

    // turn loading off
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Additionally, how would I then access this `page` variable in the backend? Here's my code for the backend:

```
public async getAllPosts(): Promise<GetPostsResponse> {
    try {
        const posts: any[] = await this.postModel.getAllPosts();

        if (!posts.length) {
            // There aren't any posts in the system
            return { success: false, message: "posts are not available" };
        } else {
            return { success: true, message: "posts found", posts };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return { success: false, error };
    }
}
```